# as of late vs of late

Tags: differences, syntactic-analysis

Which is correct? Is it "as of late" or "of late", is the "as" part necessary?

Also, can you give me a couple of different examples of sentences using the two? Is there a word that is used similarly to those particular words, that i can use to substitute the words "as of late" and "of late" with, so i don't get confused and know how to use them?

Does the following sentence "and as of late he has agreed to return home" make sense? If not, then can you restate the sentence?

EDIT: The thing is I've already used the word recently (twice) in the same paragraph and i'm meant to be writing a formal letter. 
Is the sentence correct or not? Because this is the first time I've used this site and the answers are "disorderly".

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some evidence that ***as*** of late (in the sense of *recently*) was perhaps a bit more common a century or two ago, but I think including ***as*** has never been the norm. For all that, I can't really imagine a context where OP's example...

> *"and as of late he has agreed to return home"*

...would be considered "natural", even if we removed ***as***. The reason it doesn't work is because *of late* in such contexts means ***during*** the time period stretching from the present moment to the relatively recent past. That's to say, things happening *of late* are normally things which either take some time to complete, or which can happen repeatedly (unlike, say, a single act of agreement).

As @Edwin succinctly notes, *lately/of late* apply to [durative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/durative) (rather than ["punctive"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/non-continuous)) recent actions.

---

In OP's case, the natural phrasing would be...

> *"and he [has] recently agreed to return home"*

Comment: Or "and he has *lately* agreed ...", which connects to the original quote.

Comment: @andy256: You might just about get away with that, I suppose. There is one instance of ["he has lately agreed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+has+lately+agreed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. But it looks like a citation of a Victorian original, and against that you have to weigh over 3300 instances of ["he has recently agreed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+has+recently+agreed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: Interesting numbers. I must check who that brilliant author is!

Comment: @andy256: 'Lately' seems to be used more for durative rather than punctive recent practices / states. 'Recently' is used with either. This compares with FF's analysis.

Comment: @Edwin: Those are *excellent* words to identify the distinction! I'll add them to the answer text.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *as of late* is generally used in the same sense as the words *recently* or *lately*. This diction would fit best when, perhaps, inquiring (a person) of their **recent** state of being. Example: "How have you been as of late?" can be used when asking how a person has been lately. Another common usage of the phrase *as of late* is "You've been very busy as of late!", which would also be perfectly acceptable when making a remark to a person's behavior.
Your sentence, "and as of late he has agreed to return home", doesn't make sense to me because, as aforementioned, *as of late* is indicative of a something happening only recently. I believe that your sentence would sound far better if written as: "And, before long, he agreed to return home." or "Lately, his perspective shifted and he has finally agreed to come home." However, I do not know in which context your sentence is being used, so I cannot offer much help there. My apologies!